# How to receive a payload from an external Python script in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to figure out how my index page can listen for and receive the payload from another Python script I'm running. The Python script sends the payload using:

```
requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/", params=payload)
```

(the payload for now is `payload = {"name":'Dave'}`

What do I need to do on the Flask side of things to capture (no need to store it in a DB) it in a variable (maybe in something simple like `flask.g`)?

My `index.html` (in my template looks like this right now):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ location.mspace }} - Makerspace </title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Hello, {{ user.nickname }}!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my `views.py` looks like this:

```
from flask import render_template
from app import app

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    location = {'mspace': 'Central Library'}
    user = {'nickname': 'David'}
    return render_template('index.html',
                            location = location,
                            user = user)
```

But I want to replace `user` with the payload from my other Python script.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `request` object form Flask you can grab the data out of the post request:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    location = {'mspace': 'Central Library'}
    user = {'nickname': request.data.get('name', some_default)}
    return render_template('index.html',
                            location = location,
                            user = user)
```

Alternatively if you want to do something different whether or not there was a `POST` or a `GET` your view should look something like this.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do some stuff
    else:
        # do some other stuff
```

Comment: Hey Ian - I tried your first example and got an `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'` error

Comment: What does `print(request.data)` out put?

Comment: `127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jul/2015 11:46:38] "POST /index?name=Dave HTTP/1.1" 200 -` (when I comment out the other code) --- also moved over to the second suggestion since I will probably need to a different GET

Comment: So it's weird that I'm getting the payload correctly - but it's treating `get` as a string for some reason(?)

Comment: Ok so I think I have this figured out - because the parameters are passed in the URL I need to use `requests.args.get` (or at least now I'm getting `127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jul/2015 14:20:15] "POST /index?name=Dave HTTP/1.1" 200 -` without error)